# Video quality goes bad when add video to kdenlive?

Tags: 12.04, video-editor, screencast, recordmydesktop, kdenlive

I have used many screencast programs and every time i add output recording to kdenlive for editing, it shows pixelated video. Quality of video becomes very low and i can't figure out the reason for that.

Is there anything related to project settings. My project settings are set to HDV 1440 * 1080i 25fps

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the "project monitor" in Kdenlive (which is the box to the top right in which you see your video), that's not the quality you get when you finally render (finish and export) your video. The preview looks bad but the output should be as fine as the recorded video.